# Devise a test for divisibility of an integer by 11, in terms of properties of its digits

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Using the fact that $10 \equiv-1 \pmod{11}$, devise a test for divisibility of an integer by $11$, in terms of properties of its digits.

Approach:

Let the number with its digits $a_0\cdots a_n$ be represented as $f(x)=a_0x^n+\cdots+a_n$. By exhaustion $f(-1)=0$ if the number is divisible by $11$, so $f(10)$ is divisible by $11$. Do I have to prove my conjecture? or it's trivial.

Comment: It should be mentioned that perhaps the result will be nonzero yet the number is still a multiple of eleven.  How about the number $50501=11\cdot 4591$.  $f(-1)$ in this case equals $11$, not zero.  How do you correct for this discrepancy?

Comment: if f(1) is 0 or 11?

Comment: But then that fails for larger numbers.  What about the number $9090909090909090909090 = 11\cdot 826446280991735537190$.  You would have $f(-1)$ as $99$... Are you familiar with the test for divisibility by nine?

Comment: ok, so if f(-1) is a multiple of 11?

Comment: But $f$ is supposed to tell us if something is a multiple of eleven in the first place, so saying "a number is divisible by eleven iff it is divisible by eleven" doesn't tell us much.  How do we know if $f(-1)$ is divisible by eleven?...  Changing notation, let $g(n)$ be the function to test if the number $n$ is a multiple of $11$ doing as you described, alternately adding and subtracting the digits.  What happens if we do $g(g(g(\dots g(n)\dots)))$?  Will we "end" and reach a stable position?  Always?  Really?  Why do we know this?  This step actually would require proof.

Comment: Eventually we have to reach 0 right?. At every iteration, the number decreases approaching 0.